# Expected value of sock pairs from k choices

Tags: probability

Suppose you have *N* pairs of socks in a drawer and you pick out *K* socks. What is the average number of pairs of socks that you will have if you repeat this experiment a large number of times? I know the answer is $\frac{K \choose 2}{2N-1}$ but I am unsure of the proof. This question is different from  [Expected value of sock pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894509/expected-value-of-sock-pairs) because the proof I am looking for is taken as a given in that question.

Comment: Hint: use linearity.  What's the probability that the $i^{th}$ pair is chosen?

Comment: @lulu I understand that there are $2N \choose K$ possible selections, but am unsure where to go from there. Are there $K \choose 2i$ ways of placing the $i^{th}$ pair?

Comment: Placing into what?  Can you compute the probability that a given pair will be selected?  How many selections contain the pair?  How many selections in total are there?

Comment: @lulu I am having an issue figuring out "how many selections contain the pair". There are $2N \choose K$ total selections. What I was trying to say before was that you have $K \choose 2i$ ways of placing _i_ pairs into _K_ possible slots, although I do not think this helps much.

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant.  Just pick a pair.  What is the probability that this particular pair is amongst the $k$ chosen socks?

Comment: The probability of a particular pair being among _K_ socks is $K \choose 2$, but this changes the total selection since you can no longer choose from _K_ socks if 2 were already taken out of the pool

Comment: @playfuljog the **probability** of a particular pair being among $K$ socks is still a *probability* and as such is always between $0$ and $1$.  $\binom{K}{2}$ on the other hand is larger than one and could not be a probability.  Try again.

Comment: This is true, I did not mean for the final answer to be $K \choose 2$, it should be $\frac{K \choose 2}{X}$ but I was unsure of how to find X, the total number of possible selections. I initially thought $X = {2N \choose K}$ but does that change now that we removed two socks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_i$ be the random variable that takes the value $1$ if the $i$th pair is selected, and $0$ otherwise (i.e. if only one sock or no socks of this pair are selected).

Then what you want is:

\begin{align}
\sum_i^{N} \mathbb{E}[A_i] &= N\mathbb{E}[A_i] \\
&= N \times P(\text{pair $i$ is chosen}) \\
&= N \times \frac{{K\choose 2}}{{K\choose 2} +  K(2N-K) + {2N-K \choose 2}} \\
&= N \times \frac{\frac{K(K-1)}{2} } {\frac{K(K-1)}{2} +  K(2N-K) + \frac{(2N-K)(2N-K-1)}{2}} \\
&= N \times \frac{K(K-1)}{K(K-1) + 2K(2N-K) + (2N-K)(2N-K-1)} \\
&= N \times \frac{K(K-1)}{K^2 - K + 4KN - 2K^2 + 4N^2 -4KN + K^2 - 2N + K}\\
&= N \times \frac{K(K-1)}{4N^2 - 2N } \\
&= \frac{K(K-1)}{2(2N - 1) } \\
&= \frac{K \choose 2}{2N - 1}
\end{align}

The third line is obtained from counting cases (i.e. 2 socks in $K$ socks, 1 sock in $K$ socks and 1 sock in $2N-K$ socks, 2 socks in $2N-K$ socks).

Comment: Can you please explain the first two lines? I understand that we are looking for the expected value, but why are we summing the expected value of each pair being chosen?

Comment: @playfuljog because the total number of pairs chosen is the sum of the number of times we answer yes to the question "is the $i$'th pair chosen?" and we remember that expectation is linear, so $\Bbb E[X+Y]=\Bbb E[X]+\Bbb E[Y]$

Comment: For the third line I think we can say the denominator is actually $2N(2N-1)$ and the sum is going from $i=1$ to $2N$ since the pool of socks is twice the pairs. This gives the same answer you received but with much less algebra involved